# Machine readable number of updates? Alternative to /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check?

Tags: shell-script, apt, upgrade

`/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check` (from update-notifier-common package) was a fine tool. [But it's going to be removed from Debian.](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/update-notifier-common)

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
28 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check
28;0  ~/whonix_dot/Whonix $
```

Are there any machine readable (for shell scripts) alternatives to this tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `apt-get` can easily be parsed to get the number of updates.

```
$ apt-get -s dist-upgrade | grep "^[[:digit:]]\+ upgraded"
```

#### Example

```
$ apt-get -s dist-upgrade | grep "^[[:digit:]]\+ upgraded"
82 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

This can further be reduced to just the number like so:

```
$ apt-get -s dist-upgrade | grep -o "^[[:digit:]]\+"
82
```

Or more concisely:

```
$ apt-get -s dist-upgrade | grep -Po "^[[:digit:]]+ (?=upgraded)"
82
```

Which could be shortened to this:

```
$ apt-get -s dist-upgrade | grep -Po "^\d+ (?=upgraded)"
82
```

Comment: only problem might be that apt-get does not recognize "Security updates".

Answer (score 3):

If apt-get is run with a different language, its output will look different.  In principle it would be better to use a command like `apt-get dist-upgrade -s --quiet=2 | grep ^Inst`.  It could then be piped through `wc -l` to generate a number.

This is the approach used by `apticron`.  The abbreviation `Inst` is documented in the apt-get manual pages for all languages.

---

In practice, the only difference I noticed with `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 apt-get ...` was `[J/n]` instead of `[Y/n]`.  `apt-get` is supposed to be more stable for scripts, at least compared to the new `apt` tool.  That last is a slight disappointment; it would be nice if we could use `apt list --upgradable`.